# How can i find the document that contains and ObjectID inside a array

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB database, with a clients collection with this document:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("535a3bc1deaf501ff87d188f"),
    "address" : "ghjk",
    "name" : "ghjk",
    "ni" : "12345678m",
    "orders" : [ 
        "534e53012817e40b1995d0d8"
    ],
    "phone" : "655333004",
    "surname" : "ghjk"
}
```

Now, i need to find the document in my collection that contains the id 534e53012817e40b1995d0d8 inside orders array..

```js
db.clients.findOne({"534e53012817e40b1995d0d8":{$in:"orders"}});
```

This give me a error:

> uncaught exception: error: { "$err" : "invalid query", "code" : 12580 }

How can i do it this?

Comment: `db.clients.findOne({"orders":"534e53012817e40b1995d0d8"});`

Comment: lol you took it literally, its the other way around. Ref : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

Answer (score 1):

A simple find on orders providing the value will do the job:

```
db.clients.find({"orders":"534e53012817e40b1995d0d8"})
```

If you want to use the `"$in"` operator you have to use this expression (first comes the tag where to search in and than a list of matching values listed as an array) see the [doc of $in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array):

```
db.clients.find({"orders":{"$in":["534e53012817e40b1995d0d8"]}})
```